# Flutter - Text on left, icons to right align inside the same row

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a post footer with likes indicator (text) on left and few icons on the right side. However I am failing to figure out how to align the text to left, icons to right.

Code:

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

              children: [
              
                Container(
                 
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        CupertinoPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => Comments(post: widget.post),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "${widget.post.notes} likes",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
         
                Wrap(
                  children: [
                Container(
                    child: AnimatedIconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                        });
                      },
                      icons: [
                        AnimatedIconItem(
                          icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.arrow,
                              size: 25, color: Colors.grey),
                          
                        ),
                        AnimatedIconItem(
                          icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.arrow,
                              size: 25, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  
                  ),
                Container(
                   
                    child: AnimatedIconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _toggleFavorite(widget.post.id);
                        });
                      },
                      icons: [
                        AnimatedIconItem(
                          icon: Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.heart,
                            size: 25,
                            color: _isFavorited
                                ? Colors.red[500]
                                : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        AnimatedIconItem(
                          icon: Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.heart,
                            size: 25,
                            color: _isFavorited
                                ? Colors.red[500]
                                : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),


                ]),


              ],
            ),
```

I tried to wrap the icons which I could then align to right but I can't do that. If I wrap it with Align, the icons disappear alltogether out of view (I suppose align's width is 100% and it goes to next line).

How I can align the text to left and icons to right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- wrap your text in a `Expanded` widget to take all the remaining space
  in the row, leaving all other widgets align to the end,
- wrap you icons in another `Row` and use `mainAxisAlignment` property in the firs one with `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`

Comment: Thank you! The second option did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `mainAxisAlignment` of the `Row` to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, will do just that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately it's not enough for me. I need to "fine tune" them more to right.